# Trying to copy file and getting 'file does not exist' error

Tags: java, nio, java-io, nio2, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to copy files from 1 directory to another after re-naming them but keep getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\talain\Desktop\marketingOriginal\FX Rates\FY17\Q11\Week_12___February_12_2016.xls -> C:\Users\talain\Desktop\fakeOnedrive\FX Rates\FY17\Q11\0
```

My code:

```
public class shortenFilenameClass 
{
    static String absolutePathLocal =   "C:\\Users\\talain\\Desktop\\marketingOriginal".replace('\\', '/'); //path to original files
    static String absolutePathOnedrive= "C:\\Users\\talain\\Desktop\\fakeOnedrive".replace('\\', '/'); //path to onedrive

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {           
            System.out.println(absolutePathLocal.length());
            File local = new File(absolutePathLocal);
            File onedrive = new File(absolutePathOnedrive);
            int fileCount = 0;

            File[] filesInDir = local.listFiles();
            manipulateFiles(filesInDir, fileCount);
        }

        public static void manipulateFiles(File[] filesInDirPassed, int fileCount) throws IOException
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < filesInDirPassed.length; i++) 
            {
                    File currentFile = filesInDirPassed[i];
                    if(currentFile.isDirectory())
                    {
                        String local = currentFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        //String onedrive = current
                        manipulateFiles(currentFile.listFiles(), fileCount);
                    }
                    String name = currentFile.getName();
                    System.out.println("old filename: " + name);
                    String newName = String.valueOf(fileCount);
                    fileCount++;


                    File oldPath = new File(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("oldPath: " + oldPath);

                    //currentFile.renameTo(new File(oldPath.toString()));
                    System.out.println("currentFile: " + currentFile);

                    String pathExtension = new String(currentFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(42));
                    pathExtension = pathExtension.replaceAll(name, newName);
                    File newPath = new File(absolutePathOnedrive + "/" + pathExtension);
                    System.out.println("newPath: " + newPath);
                    copyFileUsingJava7Files(oldPath, newPath);

                    File finalPath = new File(absolutePathOnedrive + "" + name);
                    //newPath.renameTo(new File(finalPath.toString()));
                    //copyFileUsingJava7Files(newPath, finalPath);
                    System.out.println("renamed: " + name + "to: " + newName + ", copied to one drive, and changed back to original name");
            }
        }


        private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
            Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
        }
}
```

Comment: No you aren't. You are getting `NoSuchFileException`. Do all the target directories exist? NB `File oldPath = new File(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());` is entirely equivalent to `File oldPath = currentFile;`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is being told that `C:\Users\talain\Desktop\marketingOriginal\FX Rates\FY17\Q11\Week_12___February_12_2016.xls -> C:\Users\talain\Desktop\fakeOnedrive\FX Rates\FY17\Q11\0` is a file, which isn't true. Check the line where the error originates from and see if you are using a lambda expression anywhere.

Comment: I dobut it. More likely the entire message is coming from `Files.copy()`, showing both source and target, to assist in debugging.

Comment: That's not how this exception works. The `NoSuchFileException` displays the source file.